# Clamp width of new Shimano brake levers

Tags: brakes, shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

Can anyone measure the width of the clamp (the dimension parallel to the bar) of the new XT M8100 12 speed Shimano brake levers?

I want to know the amount of 'bar space' the clamp takes up.

The width of either the XTR M9100 or SLX M7100 levers would be fine as well.

Comment: Do you mean the XT8100 groupset ?   Shimano's specs are at 
 https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/deore-xt-m8100/BL-M8100.html  but it doesn't give a bar diameter, just "Compatible Shifting Lever Mount: Clamp band, I-SPEC EV" and "Clamp Band Type: Open clamp"

Comment: @Criggie yeah preferably the XT but any X100 groupset (XTR, XT, or SLX) brake levers. I was hoping someone here had acquired a pair and could measure the width of the clamp for me

Comment: Wouldn’t  this just be the standard MTB bar diameter - 22.3mm?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'm not talking about the clamping diameter (that's obviously the handlebar grip diameter), I'm talking about the width (the measurement parallel to the bar) of the lever's clamp. In essence, it's the amount of 'bar space' the clamp takes up.

Comment: The dimension you are looking for is not obvious from the wording if your question

Comment: Oh, apologies. I've edited the question. I hope such edit and my previous comment will clear up further misunderstanding.

Comment: I edited to make your question clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, the Shimano XT 12s brake lever. It's roughly 17mm

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.